# How to unique validation two value that one of them has punctuations in yii2?

Tags: jquery, validation, yii2, unique

In my form, I've a *textfield* that has been set with `jquery-masked-input`, this is the *jquery* script:

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#reg-number").mask("99.999.999.9-999.999");
});
</script>
```

and then, the value will be saved into database without *punctuation*. So when I input value like this:
[image]

will be save in *mysSQL* database like this:

[image]

But I need to set this field as *unique*.
So I add this validation in my **model.php**:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['regNumber'], 'required'],
        [['regNumber'], 'string', 'max' => 32, 'min' => 15],
    ];
}
```

But it didn't work, I guess it because the value from *textfield* contain punctuation and in the database column doesn't contain punctuation.

#### How do I can make it work?

Thanks

Comment: You are right. Convert your input into normal string before validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Filter validator.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#filter)

```
['regNumber', 'filter', 'skipOnArray' => true, 'filter' => function ($value) {
   return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "", $value);
}],
[['regNumber'], 'string', 'max' => 32, 'min' => 15],
[['regNumber'], 'unique'],
```

Not tested though :)